# repository management for backend relying on database without using an ORM tool

Tags: c#, sql, git, asp.net-core, database-migration

When setting up a backend project with a database most times I'm using an ORM tool to deal with the database stuff. Therefore the database schema and the migrations are coupled to the backend code and I can keep it within my backend repository.

Now I'm creating multiple projects relying on one database type only and plain SQL has to be used.

I would like to know about the best practises to deal with the additional "database project". Meaning Database - Backend - Frontend. Should I put the database scheme into an own repository? Then I could put SQL scripts like *MigrationFrom1To2* into this repository too.

The problem that comes to my mind is that when working with many developers on the database and backend project how to keep both projects synchronized? Let's assume there's a pull request for the backend code that expects a new database table which doesn't exist yet. Then you would have to wait for the database repository to implement that feature too (add link that leads to the issue of the other repository). And by doing so every backend developer would then have to pull the latest database migration script to update his own local database, so he would have to check for new database migrations before working on the backend.

Currently I know how to manage projects with ORMs but it would be nice if someone could explain how to manage projects with plain SQL (one database is fine). If it helps I'm using MariaDb and .NET Core. Especially when it comes to automated builds and Docker (using Github Actions or something else).

Comment: 1. Keep both projects in same version control repository. 2. Have automated tests which covers most important `business logic` - `database` interactions.

Comment: thanks for your reply. When developing on the backend project how does one developer know that he has to migrate to the newest database version? Is there a way to automate his local database schema?

Comment: You would have a method which executes all migrations, which would be called every time application starts.

Comment: but how does the application know about the database migrations without using an ORM? Let's say developer 1 executed the sql script "migrateFrom14To15" two months ago. And now the current migration is "migrateFrom35To36". Both files are just sql scripts. How does the code know it has to start with migration 15 up to the latest one?

Comment: Same way as ORM does it. Database will have a table to record applied migrations, every time application apply some new migration it will add this migration id to the table. With such approach application will be able to apply only new migrations.

Comment: Are you sure? So my database has a table like `DB_Meta_Info` with a column version e.g. 23243 and maybe a timestamp and the code will update the database based on this record?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/history-table

Comment: @Question3r If I understood well, you want based on your table version to update automatically your models in several applications?

Comment: @SteliosGiakoumidis currently I would just like to know how to manage big projects with many developers relying on a single database using raw SQL instead of an ORM :)

Comment: @Fabio so on application start I would connect to the database, run a select on the version table, read the current migration and run all migrations up to the latest one?

Comment: @Question3r check the answer. I think it fits quite well to your needs.

Comment: @Question3r, yes this can be one approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In multiple projects we were in the same situation as yours and here's how we resolved it.

**Situation**

A single database was used for multiple related things. Contractors were working on a subset of application that relied on the database. Employees were working on another subset of the application on the same database. DBAs were in charge of migrations.

**Repositories**

We had 2 repositories - one for application development and another for database. Contracts and employees were writing code in the app repository. DB changes were happening in db repository. DBAs were migrating off of db repositories. App change control team was deploying code from app repository. DBAs and app change control teams were coordinated enough to deploy the right thing in the right way.

**Branching strategy**

Contractor created a feature branch (e.g. user-preferences) on the app and db repository. Changes to DB would go in db repository. Changes to app would go in app repository. As soon as enough code was written that relied on their db changes, they'd feature flag the release and push it out. Change management and DBAs reviewed pull request of user-preferences branch in both repositories together to ensure that they could deploy correctly and then merge branches to master and go through their release process. Feature flag was turned ON and OFF in a controlled environment to ensure that there were no post-production issues. Team members merged multiple times during the day. This method worked well. As you might notice, CI/CD wasn't fully automated. Teams spoke to each other about changes they were making to DB, so everyone knew what to expect.

**Trunk based development**

In a different situation, we decided to create local branch in app and db repositories. We'd test code and db changes and merge cleanly as soon as possible. DBA and change management teams deployed daily to production after going through QA, pre-production checks etc. Surprisingly, we didn't have as many conflicts and the ones we had were easy to resolved. We emphasized on creating database changes and pushing it to master as soon as devs had tested their theories. DB changes went ahead of code.

Just like a feature flag, developers checked for their db dependencies before allowing user interaction. If, somehow, db changes their code relied on weren't found, a graceful message would show up and an email would end up for change management to review dependencies. Again, surprisingly, things went quite well.

**More complex example**

A regulated company had multiple contracting teams, some doing Agile, some waterfall, some using their own concocted development methodologies. Company's staff had multiple teams with kind of the same differences as different contractors. They all had to work together to create features, fix issues etc. Sounds chaotic, right? They created a daily CAB meeting - CAB stands for Change Approval Board. Each team would spend 5 minutes educating the CAB what they were intending to push to production and their dependencies. There were different repositories and version control systems.

Very small changes were allowed to be made and pushed to production. Large changes would go in a giant batch with great fanfare. Change management team gathered code from various repos/version control systems, played it in their sim (simulation) environment (db first, then app changes) and then planned for production. Large changes were in long lasting branches that were updated with the small changes nightly. The month when large changes were to go out, small changes would pause for a few days. Large changes would go out and then small changes would resume. Frankly, it was nowhere close to perfect but it worked as long as 2 FTEs were watching deployments like a hawk.

Common thing in both companies was that app developers featured flagged and ran a pre-flight checklist to ensure that all dependencies were in place for their feature to run successfully. That way, if something got missed, error was logged and users were gracefully informed what to do/who to call.

Comment: thanks for your reply. So let's assume there are 5 database admins creating 20 database changes per day. Backend developers needs to fetch the latest database migration files each day =?

Comment: There were a couple of DBAs and a couple of change management folks creating as many changes as needed each day. And yes, everyone merged changes to owe their local repo up to date multiple times a day.

Comment: and what was the naming convention for migration files? because when working with "migration15to16" on multiple branches the order will break very fast :) and when using timestamps, they might break too

Comment: In one case the convention was some-name-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss.sql that allowed automation to sequentially update db based on timestamp. In another case there was no specific convention. In both cases, commits were tied to issue management system. When ticket 1-10 had to be released, change management team ensured that all code and db changes for those tickets was bundled. Breaks can happen. Once you get in the rhythm and teams understand each other, it gets easier. No matter how much we discuss conventions, you will find solutions only when you give a technique a shot.

Comment: Hm ok so it's not possible to identify the script order by the script name ... was hoping for a bullet proof technique :)

Comment: Correct, not by script name; we ordered by timestamp. We combined automation with human judgement to make it foolproof for us. It took time, discussions and collaboration. Based on the good questions you've asked, I am confident that once you start with a method/any method, you will be able to tweak it incrementally to make it as foolproof as your situations demand. You got this!

Answer (score 1):

Many applications connecting towards the same database is generally a bad idea, and this is one of the main reasons people are turning towards microservices. So they have data isolation and one service is not related to another's service database.

If you have one big solution handling many many projects, I would suggest you use

[DbUp](https://dbup.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

*DbUp is a .NET library that helps you to deploy changes to SQL Server databases. It tracks which SQL scripts have been run already, and runs the change scripts that are needed to get your database up to date.*

It is not an ORM, and it uses pure SQL. You create a list of SQL scripts in you code, it is part of your source control as well, and every time you start your application you check if all migration are applied and if not it applies last changes.

Migration check and database update can be automated

1. As [part of the CI/CD pipelines](https://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/setting-up-dbup-in-azure-pipelines/).
2. As a startup task in your applications that runs when the application starts every time. You can find an example of how to set up a startup task in [Andrew Lock's](https://andrewlock.net/running-async-tasks-on-app-startup-in-asp-net-core-part-1/) blog.

Comment: sorry I think you misunderstood or I didn't exaplain quite well. I don't want to access a single database with many projects at the same time. For many projects, I just want to avoid using an ORM :)

Comment: @Question3r my answer would be again to use DbUp. It is very lightweight and well established. You use pure SQL, no ORMs. Since it is SQL script, you can even use it to prepopulate tables with it (constants table for example).

Comment: As far as I understood the sql scripts have to be within the backend project right? So the database managers would have to work with the backend project to handle the db?

Comment: @Question3r That depends on you. The scripts would be part of a project.If you want all changes to be approved by a dba, it would be better if this is a stand alone project that keeps track of all databases and is managed by a dba. If developers can make db changes, this could be a start up task in every backend project.

Comment: You can take a look here: https://github.com/steliosgiakoumidis/StockExchange I have a seperate project that you can run and set up the database so you can run the actual application